# How to setup dynamic variables before request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, cross-domain

I have a configuration of a blog factory like this :

```
- blogcrea.com/a-blog/ -> blog = a-blog
- blogcrea.com/another-blog/ -> blog = another-blog
- blogcrea.com/blog-with-custom-domain/ -> blog = blog-with-custom-domain
```

But I also want to use fully domain names like this :

```
- www.myawsomeblog.com -> blog = blog-with-custom-domain
```

I host a lot of blogs and there is a lot of domain names also, so I cannot do a per case treatment.

I am thinking using before_dispatch (http://m.onkey.org/dispatcher-callbacks) to set up a dynamic blog name and use dynamically a path variable in the routes.rb. I was thinking of a global var but it seems a bad idea ([Why aren't global (dollar-sign $) variables used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927479/rails-why-no-one-use-global-dollar-sign-variable)).

Do you think it's a good idea ? What is the best way to store the blog name during the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle it before the request. You have two types of urls: `blogcrea.com/[blogname]/[other params]` and `[customdomain]/[other params]`

The best way to handle this is with two sets of routes depending on the domain:

```
constrains(CheckIfBlogCrea) do
    match '/:blog(/:controller(/:action(/:id)))' # Build your routes with the :blog param
end

match '/(:controller(/:action(/:id)))' # Catch the custom domain routes
```

Matcher for common domain:

```
module CheckIfBlogCrea

    def self.matches?(request)
        request.host == 'blogcrea.com' 
    end

end
```

Now you know the routes will always match. Ofcourse you still have to know which blog to show. This can easily be done in the `ApplicationController` with a `before_filter`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :load_blog


    protected

    def load_blog
        # Custom domain?
        if params[:blog].nil?
            @blog = Blog.find_by_domain(request.host)
        else
            @blog = Blog.find_by_slug(params[:blog])
        end
        # I recommend to handle the case of no blog found here
    end

end
```

Now in your actions you'll have the `@blog` object that tells you which blog it is, it's also available in the views when rendering.

Answer (score -1):

you should use global variable.but take care during using it.initialize it with common place so you can change it whenever you require. like

```
- blogcrea.com/a-blog/ -> blog = $a-blog
- blogcrea.com/another-blog/ -> blog = $another-blog
- blogcrea.com/blog-with-custom-domain/ -> blog = $blog-with-custom-domain
```

Comment: Don't use globals, it breaks the statelessness of rails and causes complications when you have multiple instances of your app running at once (like you would on production).