# Adding HTML elements to an array

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, element

I'm writing a script using Ruby, Mechanize and Nokogiri to scrape the source attributes from iframe elements on a webpage, and if there's more than one, store them inside an array for later use.

So I have the following code which works, but my question is; Is there a more elegant way of achieving this? Say, something along the lines of `iframe.<some_method_like_length>` instead of using the `i` counter?

```
i = 0
doc.search("//span/iframe").each do |iframe|
    $ifrmsrc[i] = iframe.attribute("src")
    i += 1
end
i = 0
```

```
#LATER USE :)
$ifrmsrc.length.times do |g|
    puts $ifrmsrc.at(g)
end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code and belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use the [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) operator to add an item to the end of an Array.

```
ifrmsrc = []

doc.search("//span/iframe").each do |iframe|
  ifrmsrc << iframe.attribute("src")
end
```

...or, to be more Rubyish, use [`Enumerable#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), which executes the given block for each item in an Enumerable and returns a new Array with the results.

```
ifrmsrc = doc.search("//span/iframe").map {|iframe| iframe["src"] }
```

(If `ifrmsrc` already exists and already has data in it that you want, use `+=` instead of `=` since `=` will overwrite it. However, from your code I'm guessing this is the only place items will be added to the array, so there's no need to define it ahead of time.)

P.S. [Don't use global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927479/why-no-one-use-global-dollar-sign-variable) (i.e. variables that start with `$`). It's just a bad practice.

Comment: "It's just a bad practice." It's code-smell; Don't use global variables unless it's understand when and why they should be used.

Comment: Instead of `iframe.attribute("src")` use `iframe['src']` for conciseness.

Comment: For readability, I recommend CSS over XPath, especially for cases like this where the added capabilities of XPath aren't needed. XPath tends to add a lot of visual noise, where `search('span iframe')` is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer more XPath:

```
ifrmsrc = doc.xpath("//span/iframe/@src").map(&:value)
```

And later, you don't need the index to iterate values:

```
ifrmsrc.each{ |src| puts src }
```

Or, if you *do* need the index for other reasons:

```
ifrmsrc.each.with_index{ |src,i| puts "Source ##{i} is #{src}" }
```

Though, if you just want the values, one on each line:

```
puts ifrmsrc
```